# Why does my reverse() method reverse both MyLinkedList objects?

Tags: java, this, reverse, doubly-linked-list

I'm making a Doubly-Linked-List class, but I'm stuck on this reverse() method. I want the reverse() method to make and return a new MyLinkedList that is a reverse of the old one without changing the old one.

```
public MyLinkedList<AnyType> reverse()
{
   MyLinkedList<AnyType> list = this;

   for(int i=0,j=list.theSize-1; i < list.theSize/2; i++, j--)
       list.swap(i,j);

   return list;
}

public void swap(int index1, int index2)
{
        if(index1 == index2)
            return;
        else if(index1 > theSize-1 || index2 > theSize-1)
        {
            try{
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
            {
                System.out.println("IndexOutOfBoundsException\n");
                return;
            }             
        }
        Node<AnyType> first;
        Node<AnyType> last;
        if(index1 < index2)
        {
            first = this.getNode(index1);
            last = this.getNode(index2);
        }
        else
        {
            first = this.getNode(index2);
            last = this.getNode(index1);
        }
        if((index1 == 0 && index2 == theSize -1) ||(index1 == theSize -1 && index2 == 0))
        {   
            first.next.prev = last;
            last.prev.next = first;

            first.prev = last.prev;
            last.next = first.next;

            first.next = endMarker;
            endMarker.prev = first;
            last.prev = beginMarker;
            beginMarker.next = last;
        }

        else if(Math.abs(index1-index2) == 1)
        {
            first.next = last.next;
            last.prev = first.prev;
            first.prev = last;
            last.next = first;
            last.prev.next = last;
            first.next.prev = first;
        }

        else
        {
            Node<AnyType> tempNext = last.next;
            Node<AnyType> tempPrev = last.prev;

            last.next.prev = first;
            last.prev.next = first;
            first.prev.next = last;
            first.next.prev = last;

            last.next = first.next;
            last.prev = first.prev;
            first.next = tempNext;
            first.prev = tempPrev;
        }
}
public static void main( String [ ] args )
{
    MyLinkedList<Integer> lst = new MyLinkedList<>( );
    MyLinkedList<Integer> lst2 = new MyLinkedList<>( );

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
            lst.add( i );
    System.out.println("Original List: " + lst);

    lst2 = lst.reverse();
    System.out.println("Original List: " + lst);
    System.out.println("Reversed List: " + lst2);
}
```

Here's my output:

```
Original List: [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
Original List: [ 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 ]
Reversed List: [ 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 ]
```

As you can see, the original list is getting reversed as well. Why is this happening?

Comment: Language tag please. I'll tag this as java for now. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's why:

```
lst2 = lst.reverse();
```

You're calling `reverse()` on `lst` so `lst` is going to be reversed. Then you assign the result ot `lst2` which is going to be reserved as well. The solution is to make a deep copy of `lst`, assign it `lst2` and call

```
lst2.reverse();
```

Instead of this: `MyLinkedList<AnyType> list = this;`

Try this:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    list.add( this.getNode(i) );
```

Comment: That sounds like it would work, but I tried that. I used "lst2 = lst;  lst2.reverse();"  and I get the exact same output. I don't know why since my reverse method doesn't touch the calling object at all.

Comment: So `lst.reserve()` and printing out `lst` won't have a reversed list?

Comment: Actually, that reverses the list, too.

Comment: That does work, but I need my reverse method to return a new MyLinkedList with reversed elements. Do you see anything in my reverse method that could be causing the problem?

Comment: Thanks for helping me! That works! Do you know why, though?  In my original reverse() method, was list just a reference pointer to the current object even though I was trying to make list be a new object?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does my reverse() method reverse both MyLinkedList objects?

Because you don't *have* two objects. You only have one object with two references. So, you reverse the order in the object, so the new order is visible via both references.

Comment: So, "this" and "list" both reference the object in the reverse() method?

Comment: Exactly. 'list = this' only copies the reference, not the object. The 'list' variable is basically pointless in this method.